# Assertions results for passed test are empty after upgrading to Jasmine2 in protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am using "resultJsonOutputFile" to write my test results in json format. Recently i have migrated to Jasmine2.0, but after that, assertions results for passed test is empty in the json output.

The issue was with assertions for only passed test cases. failed cases are perfectly fine. Before adding Jasmine2 as framework in config, i used to get assertions results for passed ones too. eg: below

```
[
{
    "description": "test1",
    "assertions": [
        {
            "passed": true
        }
    ],
    "duration": 4304
}
]
```

But after adding framework: jasmine2, the resultjsonoutput looks like this.

```
[
{
    "description": "test1",
    "assertions": [],
    "duration": 12251
},
{
    "description": "test2",
    "assertions": [
        {
            "passed": false,
            "errorMsg": "Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(\".search-box-desktop1\")",
            "stackTrace": "Error: Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector"
        }
    ],
    "duration": 14724
}
]
```

Only change I have made is framework change in config. So I am confused with output now.

Comment: Its an issue in protractor and will be getting resolved in release.    https://github.com/juliemr/protractor/commit/1c44c908260818c4e42cffebdf3cec355a85096c

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue in protractor and will be getting resolved in release. [Checked in Code](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor/commit/1c44c908260818c4e42cffebdf3cec355a85096c)